# merging cells with tabularx

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I'am writing my thesis. I want to create a table.

I'm using the tabularx environment
My code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Aditivo} & {\textbf{Quantidade (g)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
     & Carga Mineral (\%) \\
     & 20    & 30 \\
     \midrule
    Fibra & 1,266 & 252 \\
    GCC & 0,316 & 52 \\
    Amido & 0,016 & 25 \\
    ASA & 0,002 & 252 \\
    Percol & 0,00032 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab_formacao_folhas}%
\end{table}%ckquote
```

[image]

But I want merging the text "Quantidade (g)" and "Carga Mineral" in second and third column. With tabularx , I can't use multicolumn.

Comment: just use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Quantidade (g}`

Comment: I wouldn't use tabularx for this in an any case, numeric columns would look better using dcolumn or siunitx so that the digits were aligned

Comment: Can you give me a exemple of dcolumn or siunitx ?

Comment: @user46548 Please see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/dcolumn.pdf pp 1-2, and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf. There should be plenty more examples over the Internet.

Comment: @user46548 make your example a complete document so people can run it without effort, then someone might show one of a numeric alignment, but why did you think you couldn't use \multicolumn with tabularx (most of the package complication is making \multicolumn work:-)

Comment: But I want to adjust width table to page

Comment: @user46548 but the headings can still span the columns

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your comment. I want a table with the width adjust to page. So, I check some examples in internet and the people use the tabularx environment

Comment: You can use tabularx if you want but your comment that that means that you can not use \multicolumn is wrong. But please always post a complete document not just a fragment. (I would not use tabularx for this (even though I wrote that package) it is just three numeric columns so forcing the table to page width just makes it harder to read

Comment: Note that your code will not compile due to a syntax error even if you add the preamble etc.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents.

The comment about not being able to use `\multicolumn` with `tabularx` is wrong as shown in the first table below, but `tabularx` is really for adjusting the widths of *paragraphs* in `p` columns. Using it for numeric columns doesn't really produce a good result, it just spaces the table out, making it harder to read, and if you use `\centering` the numeric data isn't aligned.  I'd use a setting more like the second table where the data aligns on the `,`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
%  \centering does nothing if table is full width
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Aditivo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Quantidade (g)}}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Carga Mineral (\%)} \\
     & 20    & 30 \\
     \midrule
    Fibra & 1,266 & 252 \\
    GCC & 0,316 & 52 \\
    Amido & 0,016 & 25 \\
    ASA & 0,002 & 252 \\
    Percol & 0,00032 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab_formacao_folhas}%
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cD{,}{,}{3.7}D{,}{,}{5.1}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Aditivo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Quantidade (g)}}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Carga Mineral (\%)} \\
     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20}    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{30} \\
     \midrule
    Fibra & 1,266 & 252 \\
    GCC & 0,316 & 52 \\
    Amido & 0,016 & 25 \\
    ASA & 0,002 & 252 \\
    Percol & 0,00032 & 25 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab_formacao_folhas2}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```